# Do we have predictive knowledge of gene editing outcomes for heretofore unseen traits?

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction, genetics, genetic-engineering

We can know what genes affect what outcomes by following the trail backwards, but can we predictively know what changes to what genes would result in completely different and previously unseen outcomes? For instance, we may know what gene causes blue eyes by having found it through testing, but do we know what human gene change would result in human sight extending into the ultraviolet, or some such other specific outcome? (note that this is a for instance and not the actual meat of the question). Or are we completely limited in our knowledge of what genes might cause what outcomes by examples in nature?
The question goes to the idea of specifying "positive" evolution through gene editing (of both the host and the sex cells so that changes are inherited) rather than waiting for it to occur and then selecting it.

Comment: We know animals that can see into the UV range. It would be more like somewhere in the range of hundreds to thousands (or tens of thousands) of little alterations to genes - each of which may have an unpredictable outcome and require correcting. Not sure where the worldbuilding comes into it, can you give us a bit of context to make it on-topic (see the [ask] for clarification of our requirements) and make it a lot more specific as to what you're attempting to achieve.

Comment: As we learn more about both DNA and the epigenome, the more complicated the whole mess becomes. There are "flags" in the supposedly unused portions of DNA which may control activation of genes quite a distance away. The epigenome can activate flags. Right now, my opinion is that speculative changing DNA is a major risk. We just don't know enough - especially intergenerational effects.

Comment: We can't even work out how a protein folds up ahead of time. Ultimate effects of gene changes? No chance.

Comment: @DavidR sounds like this comment should become an answer!

Comment: Does this present-day technology limitation in any way block your worldbuilding? SciFi authors have been using futuristic gene editing to explain everything from superhumans to breathtaking monsters. Does it matter that the tech can't yet be "realistically used" in the way you intend? I'm just curious. Also, if you roll your mouse over the [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction] tags, you'll see they're mutually exclusive. Could you delete one of them? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, if you want to write an interesting story, it's hard for me to imagine the sociopolitical and theocultural chaos that could occur if gene editing ever could do what you suggest.

Comment: Find "in the pipeline" by Derek Lowe. It is a blog that covers various medial research topics. Frequent topic is finding substances to bind to a particular target. There is huge unpredictability in just that, on surface, simple task.

Comment: BTW: our receptors technically have ability to perceive UV. However, we actually evolved production of molecules in our eye lenses to filter them out, as otherwise UV would cause too much damage.

Answer (score 8):

We are barely at the beginning of understanding the complex interaction between gene expression during the organism development.

Until now any scientist who wanted to understand what a gene did, had to switch it off and try to understand what the consequences were on the organism, which is comparable to how a toddler interacts with toys: push buttons around until a causal correlation is built. Nowhere close to the engineer following the schematics to check that squeezing the nose will result in the teddy bear producing the sound of a laughter.

For example I have recently read in the news that the black death in the middle age has left us with some diseases consequence of the genome bearing the plague resisting genes.

Does it mean that we know what the consequences of being able to survive Covid19 will be? Of course, we just suspect that something will happen.

Answer (score 7):

Of course we do. Sort of. Not much. Mostly not. More realistically, we have a vague idea of what we would *hope* to obtain by adding some specific extra genes. Most usually, the results are disappointing; but sometimes, rarely, we do indeed get what we wanted, or at least something which is not bad.

Don't do this at home. Don't even *think* of doing it on humans.

But yes we do know enough to practice it routinely.

On plants. On fish. On other such organisms which are beneath our respect.

You may have heard of the unexplainable fuss some mass media organizations have stirred in regard to [genetically modified organisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetically_modified_organism). Those are perfectly normal organisms whose genomes have been altered rather directly, instead of the traditional methods of hybridization or induced mutations, followed by selection. The discipline of designing and applying direct changes to the genome of an organism with the goal of obtaining useful traits is called [genetic engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_engineering). There are literally millions of tons of genetically engineered organisms in the world.

Examples:

- [GloFish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GloFish)™ are artificially created [zebrafish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebrafish) *Danio rerio* or [tetras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetras) *Gymnocorymbus ternetzi* which have the attractive quality of fluorescing when illuminated with [blacklight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklight), that is, ultraviolet, light.

  <sup>GloFish™ is a trademark of Spectrum Brands, Inc. The generic term is genetically engineered fluorescent fish.</sup>

  Fluorescent aquarium fish were created by Dr. Zhiyuan Gong at the National University of Singapore, originally by incorporating in a zebrafish embryo the gene which encodes the [green fluorescent protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_fluorescent_protein). Nowadays you can buy zebrafish which fluoresce green, red, or orange, each line containing genes which encode for specific proteins.

  GloFish breed true, that is, a mother red-fluorescing zebrafish and a father red-fluorescing zebrafish will produce red-fluorescing little zebrafish. There is some limited evidence that wild-type female zebrafish prefer fluorescing males to the dull wild-type males.

  [image: Fluorescent zebrafish fluorescing in the dark]

  <sup>*Fluorescent zebrafish fluorescing in the dark. Photograph by Karol Głąb, [available on Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Danio_rerio_GloFish-science_institute_aquaria_05.jpg) under the [GNU Free Documentation License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en:GNU_Free_Documentation_License).*</sup>
- [Golden Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_rice) is an artificially created variety or rice *Oryza sativa* which produces and accumulates [beta-carotene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-carotene) in its seeds. It is called Golden Rice because the seeds are strikingly yellow. Golden Rice was created by Peter Bramley, Ingo Potrykus and Peter Beyer, working for an international cast of instutions including the Rockefeller Foundation, the Swiss Federal Institute of Technology and the University of Freiburg.

  Golden Rice was created by incorporating two genes responsible for the biosynthesis of beta-carotene, one from daffodils and the other from a nice little bacterium.

  The idea is that beta-carotene is a precursor of vitamin A, meaning that when humans eat it the human body coverts it into vitamin A. Normal rice does not contain any vitamin A to speak of. [Vitamin A deficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin_A_deficiency) is rampant in countries where rice is a staple food. A variety of rice which produces vitamin A is obviously useful.

  Golden Rice breeds true, meaning that if you plant seeds of Golden Rice you get Golden Rice. Since its creation, Golden Rice has been cross-bred with various local varieties of rice, thus obtaining sub-varieties which inherited the golden beta-carotene from the artificial variety and the hardness of their locally grown traditional parents.

You may notice that both examples involve the modification of the wild-type genome by the addition of genes copied from other organisms. The sad truth is that at our current level of understanding of biochemistry we cannot really design a new protein and a new biochemical process with any degree of confidence. What genetic engineers mostly do is (1) identify a protein which would be nice to have, (2) find an organism which already makes it, (3) determine which gene encodes it, (4) use ultra-modern technology to incorporate that gene into the embryo of the target organism, and finally (5) hope for the best.

But progress in unrelenting. We now have machinery which can synthesize DNA given the sequence of nucleotides. In 2010, Craig Venter, Clyde A. Hutchison III, and many others, of the J. Craig Venter Institute, were successful in synthesizing (called "DNA printing") the entire genome of a bacterium, [*Mycoplasma mycoides*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycoplasma_mycoides) starting from a computer record; the resulting DNA was then inserted into a cell of another species of bacterium, [*Mycoplasma capriolum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycoplasma_capricolum), which had its original DNA removed. The combination worked, and is considered an entirely artificial species, [*Mycoplasma laboratorium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycoplasma_laboratorium).

And now comes the moral of the story. After creating their synthetic bacterium, the researchers went through iterations trying to remove genes one by one while still maintaing a fully functional bacterium. They are currently at version 3 of *M. laboratorium*, which has a genome containing as little as 473 genes. The kicker is that *149 of these genes are of unknown function*. We know they are necessary. We have no idea what they do. And we are speaking of a *bacterium*.

Overall, the state of the art is as follows:

1. If we identify a protein which would be nice to have in an organism, and if we find an organism which makes it, and if we find the gene which encodes it, and the genes which regulate its expression, then we can try to incorporate those genes in the target organism. The rate of success is low, but non-zero. Sometimes it works as planned.
2. If we get from somewhere the sequence of nucleotides G-A-T-T-A-C-A of a novel gene, we have machinery which can print the DNA fragment which we can then try to incorporate in a bacterium and go to point 1 above.
3. We are learning more and more about how the components of the genome interact, making slow but visible progress into developing an understanding of larger and larger portions of the complete set.
4. Although at present we are nowhere near being able to *design* novel proteins, or novel biochemical pathways, which would result in some pre-defined phenotypical trait, it is clear that at some point in the future such knowlege will become available. Not now, not soon, but we are confident that such a day will eventually come in the fullness of time.

Comment: The scary thing is that people ARE trying this at home. People have injected themselves with modified DNA hoping to improve themselves. DNA modification is simple enough that people are messing around with it in "garages".